# Error installing requests_kerberos==0.12.0 in Azure DataBricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to install `requests_kerberos == 0.12.0` in Azure DataBricks, but trying to install it generates an error and does not install.

this is the cluster configuration where I am trying to install it: `Databricks Runtime Version7.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)`

also try installing the following,`% sh sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev libkrb5-dev`, but the installation never finishes.

**This is the error installing in the databricks notebook**

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /databricks/python3/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-k1b9yec8/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-k1b9yec8/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-tfttk2g6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /databricks/python3/include/site/python3.7/pykerberos Check the logs for full command output.
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Tested on:** `Databricks Runtime Version7.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)`

To install `requests_kerberos==0.12.0` in Azure DataBricks:

```
%sh
pip install requests-kerberos
```

[image]

> If you run an apt-get command without the **-y** option, you need to answer to all prompts that you get from that command interactively in order for the execution of the command to continue.

If you are using **without “-y”**, this command will be **keep on running** until we accept to answer to all prompts.

```
%sh 
sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev libkrb5-dev
```

[image]

If you are using **with “-y”** it will automatically say yes to all the prompts and **complete installation**.

```
%sh 
sudo apt-get install -y gcc python-dev libkrb5-dev
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great help, I already tried it and it works perfect

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.